# Using http session in Stateless Session Bean via @Context

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb

I have created a Web-Application that shows documents to the user.
The application uses RESTFUL Webservices to get this documents from the backend.

The EJB responsible for creating / loading the documents needs some information stored in the http session.
(There was a requirement to determine how long a document has been openend, how long loading took etc., there is data stored in the session to determine which document in which browser window was closed or updated)

My solutions to get this informations looks like this (in the SSB and an Interceptor for another SSB):

```
@Context
private HttpServletRequest request;
```

...

```
this.request.getSession().getAttribute(WINDOW_SET);
```

This solution is working.
I am not sure this is the "right way" to do it, since @Context is not really meant for use in an EJB as far as I researched until now.

I can not just pass the needed information to the EJB as an argument, since this would not work with the Interceptor used.

The question is:
Is this a valid way to build this functionality?
If not, what are the drawbacks of this solution and how could it be done better?

Answer (score 0):

No. The bean is annotated as stateless: it must be stateless. You can't expect injection of the request or the session to even work.

What a 'stateless session bean' actually means is another question, and one which I've been pondering since about 1998.

Comment: I would like to generate a log entry in the EJB module that includes the `userid` that initiated the transaction. I could pass the `userid` as a parameter value from a service bean (that has access to HttpSession) to the EJB module, but the problem is that the number of methods is too large and also there are many layers in the EJB module so I don't want to pollute the application with the `userid` field. If there should not be access to HttpSession in the EJB module, what is the best practice to store the `userid`?